# How can I convert this raw query into typeorm query builder?

Tags: typeorm

I have 3 tables, `author`, `product` and `product_author`. `author` and `product` are in many to many relationship.

I have a raw sql like this:

```
      return await self.query(
        `SELECT author.* 
        FROM author
        JOIN product_author ON author.id = product_author.author_id
        WHERE product_author.product_id = $1`,
        [productId],
      ) as Array<Author>;
```

And I want to run the same query in queryBuilder, how can I do that?

My attempt but didn't work somehow:

```
      const query = await self.createQueryBuilder()
        .innerJoinAndSelect("product.authors", "authors")
        .where({
          "product_author.product_id": productId
        })
        .getMany()
```